# Bootstrap columns not centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center 4 extra small bootstrap columns next to each other.

But when I do that it just doesn't center them.

I tried to center them with the `margin: 0 auto;` method but that didn't work.

I also tried `text-align: center;` but that also didn't work.

And also the built in `center-text` class in bootstrap.

I tried all of these methods on all the parent divs.

This is what it is right now:

[image: Current]

And this is what I want:

[image: Outcome]

This is my code right now:

```
<div class="gallery-filter">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p>
                All
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p>
                Area
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p>
                Resort
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p>
                Rinjani
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.gallery-filter > .row {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.gallery-filter {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bootstrap text-center class:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
     <p>
         All
     </p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
     <p>
         Area
     </p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
     <p>
         Resort
     </p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
     <p>
         Rinjani
     </p>
</div>
```

If still doen't work try to remove p tag
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLkoNA

Comment: Doesn't change anything. EDIT: Your codepen worked. Thanks!